# websockets.exceptions 4040 (private use), reason = Draining connection --python

Tags: python, websocket, ethereum, web3py, moralis

I keep getting this error on my websocket connection

```
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: code = 4040 (private use), reason = Draining connection
```

This is my code

```
bsc = 'wss://speedy-nodes-nyc.moralis.io/123456789/bsc/mainnet/ws'   
web3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider(bsc))
print(web3.isConnected())

def handle_event(event):
   #Web3.toJSON(event)
   print(Web3.toJSON(event))



async def log_loop(event_filter, poll_interval):
    while True:
        for event in event_filter.get_new_entries():
            handle_event(event)
        await asyncio.sleep(poll_interval)

def main():
    event_filter = myContract.events.Transfer.createFilter(fromBlock="latest")
    #block_filter = web3.eth.filter('latest')
    #tx_filter = web3.eth.filter('pending')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(
            asyncio.gather(
                #log_loop(block_filter, 2),
                #log_loop(tx_filter, 2)))
                log_loop(event_filter, 2)))
    finally:
        loop.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How can I automatically reconnect to my websocketprovider if the connection closes without exiting my running script?

I know there have been answers to similliar questions but none of them work for me.

I also know that it works when adding options in javascript to the websocketprovider

```
reconnect: {
auto: true,
delay: 10000,
maxAttempts: 10,
}
```

How would I use these options in python?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue ?
I am encountering the same probleme